# error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant while creating array of structure

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, structure

i am trying to create array of structure. 
Method i was using for creating array of structure which was working fine in Linux and Mac but this is throwing error in windows

```
uint32_t size;
Test TestArray[size];
TestArray[i] = Test;
//i
```

Error I am getting in windows

```
error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
```

I have also tried

```
typedef struct Test {
    char *x;
    char *y;
} Test;

uint32_t size;
status = napi_get_array_length(env,args[2],&size);
assert(status == napi_ok);

struct Test  testList[size];
napi_value SharePrefixObject;
for(uint32_t i=0;i<size;i++){
Test t;
testList[i]= t;
```

Question
How can resolve above error ?

Comment: C++ arrays have to be constant sized. Variable length arrays only work because of non-standard compiler extensions so they aren't portable.

Comment: Related if not the duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: ***Question How can resolve above error ?*** use a `std::vector` instead which is proper standard `c++`

Comment: `typedef struct Test` in `c++` you don't need the `typedef`

Comment: `uint32_t size; Test TestArray[size];` should be illegal on all systems or at least its Undefined Behavior on the compilers that support the non-standard VLA extension in `c++`. It's undefined behavior because `size` was not initialized before this. And if this was in the global scope an array of size 0 that can not be enlarged is not so useful.

Answer (score 2):

There are no variable length arrays in C++. The C++ way to do this is to use a vector.

Your code is very C like. The way you declare structs looks like C. The way you use pointers is idiomatically like C. Anyway, if you want to do some proper C++ programming then do this

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<Test> testList(size);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use constant for array size like:

```
Test TestArray[123]; //were 123 - max size of your's array data
```

or

```
#define TEST_ARRAY_SIZE 123

Test TestArray[TEST_ARRAY_SIZE];
```

if you need different size use something like mallok:

```
uint32_t size;
Test *TestArrayPnt;

//some ware you got a size like size = 123

TestArrayPnt = new Test[size];

//continue a program. You can use TestArrayPnt [111] were 111 some offset less than size

delete[] TestArrayPnt; //when finish
```

Comment: The malloc line is incorrect, and you should not do this in C++ anyway

Comment: @M.M how can we do it in C++ ?

Comment: I was correct the code and test it in online compiler @Shivam Kumar